# converting associative array to normal

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

If i have an array like this:

```
array(
    "unknownString" => 34, //unknown number
    "anotherString" => 32,
    "asdf" => 21
);
```

How can I convert it to this:

```
array(
    array("unknownString", 34),
    array("anotherString", 32),
    array("asdf", 21)
);
```

Comment: Related : [Converting associative arrays into normal ones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696933/converting-associative-arrays-into-normal-ones).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$array = array(
    "unknownString" => 34, //unknown number
    "anotherString" => 32,
    "asdf" => 21
);

$new_array = array();
foreach( $array as $key => $value) {
    $new_array[] = array( $key, $value);
}
```

If you wanted to, you could also use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/array_walk):

```
$new_array = array();
array_walk( $array, function( $el, $key) use( &$new_array){ 
   $new_array[] = array( $key, $el); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly different version using [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
function swap($value, $key) {
   return array( $key, $value );
}
$arr = array(
    "unknownString" => 34, //unknown number
    "anotherString" => 32,
    "asdf" => 21
);

print_r(array_map('swap', $arr, array_keys($arr)));
```